# Panning canvas after transformations in incorrect direction

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, transformation

I created a small HTML5 image viewer using HTML5 canvas and only Vanilla Javascript.

Everything works quite well, except for one thing, and that's panning after a transformation like rotate, flip and mirror. The canvas moves in the incorrect direction, which makes perfect sense.

I was able to solve this problem, 'panning after rotating'. I have a matrix which I use for the correction for the different angles (0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees). Maybe not the most pretty solution, but it works.

But when I flip or mirror the canvas, the canvas still moves in the incorrect direction. Now I can try to solve it in a similar way like I solved the 'panning after rotating' problem, but that doesn't seem right. I know it should be done differently, but how?

In my code I have commented the 'panning after rotating' solution out. Can someone give me a an example how to solve this the right way?

The Codepen with limited code:
https://codepen.io/r-w-c/pen/RwEZjGr

The Codepen with full code of the viewer here:
https://codepen.io/r-w-c/pen/dywRKJL

```js
const IMGURL = "https://i.imgur.com/hjNvQge.jpg";

const CANVASWITH = 500;
const CANVASHEIGHT = 325;
const PANSTEP = 20;

/*
var rotateMatrix = {};
rotateMatrix.left = [];
rotateMatrix.left[0] = [-1, 0];
rotateMatrix.left[90] = [0, 1];
rotateMatrix.left[180] = [1, 0];
rotateMatrix.left[270] = [0, -1];
rotateMatrix.right = [];
rotateMatrix.right[0] = [1, 0];
rotateMatrix.right[90] = [0, -1];
rotateMatrix.right[180] = [-1, 0];
rotateMatrix.right[270] = [0, 1];
rotateMatrix.up = [];
rotateMatrix.up[0] = [0, -1];
rotateMatrix.up[90] = [-1, 0];
rotateMatrix.up[180] = [0, 1];
rotateMatrix.up[270] = [1, 0];
rotateMatrix.down = [];
rotateMatrix.down[0] = [0, 1];
rotateMatrix.down[90] = [1, 0];
rotateMatrix.down[180] = [0, -1];
rotateMatrix.down[270] = [-1, 0];
*/

var canvas,
  context,
  image,
  scaledImgWidth,
  scaledImgHeight,
  startX,
  startY,
  canvasCenterX,
  canvasCenterY,
  scale,
  currentRotation;

window.onload = () => {
  loadImage();
  addEventListeners();
};

function loadImage() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = CANVASWITH;
  canvas.height = CANVASHEIGHT;
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  image = new Image();

  image.onload = function () {
    init();
    reset();
  };
  image.src = IMGURL;
}

function init() {
  scale = Math.min(canvas.width / image.width, canvas.height / image.height);
  scaledImgWidth = image.width * scale;
  scaledImgHeight = image.height * scale;
  startX = (canvas.width - scaledImgWidth) / 2;
  startY = (canvas.height - scaledImgHeight) / 2;
  canvasCenterX = canvas.width / 2;
  canvasCenterY = canvas.height / 2;
  context.save();
}

function drawImageToCanvas() {
  context.save();
  context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.restore();
  context.drawImage(image, startX, startY, scaledImgWidth, scaledImgHeight);
}

function pan(x, y) {
  context.translate(x, y);
  drawImageToCanvas();
}
function rotate(degrees) {
  context.translate(canvasCenterX, canvasCenterY);
  context.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * degrees);
  context.translate(-canvasCenterX, -canvasCenterY);
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function mirror() {
  context.translate(canvasCenterX, canvasCenterY);
  context.scale(-1, 1);
  context.translate(-canvasCenterX, -canvasCenterY);
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function flip() {
  context.translate(canvasCenterX, canvasCenterY);
  context.scale(1, -1);
  context.translate(-canvasCenterX, -canvasCenterY);
  //currentRotation = (currentRotation + 360 + 180) % 360;
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function reset() {
  context.restore();
  context.save();
  drawImageToCanvas();
  //currentRotation = 0;
}

function addEventListeners() {
  document.getElementById("rotateRight").addEventListener("click", function () {
    //currentRotation = (currentRotation + 90) % 360;
    rotate(90);
  });
  document
    .getElementById("rotateLeft")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      //currentRotation = (currentRotation + 270) % 360;
      rotate(-90);
    });
  document.getElementById("mirror").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    mirror();
  });
  document.getElementById("flip").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    flip();
  });
  document
    .getElementById("panLeft")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      pan(-PANSTEP, 0);
      //pan(
      //rotateMatrix.left[currentRotation][0] * PANSTEP,
      //rotateMatrix.left[currentRotation][1] * PANSTEP
      //);
    });
  document
    .getElementById("panRight")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      pan(PANSTEP, 0);
      //pan(
      //rotateMatrix.right[currentRotation][0] * PANSTEP,
      //rotateMatrix.right[currentRotation][1] * PANSTEP
      //);
    });
  document.getElementById("panUp").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    pan(0, -PANSTEP);
    //pan(
    //rotateMatrix.up[currentRotation][0] * PANSTEP,
    //rotateMatrix.up[currentRotation][1] * PANSTEP
    //);
  });
  document
    .getElementById("panDown")
    .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      pan(0, PANSTEP);
      //pan(
      //rotateMatrix.down[currentRotation][0] * PANSTEP,
      //rotateMatrix.down[currentRotation][1] * PANSTEP
      //);
    });
}
```

```css
.canvas-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

canvas {
  background: #777;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.canvas-controls {
  padding: 5px;
}

button span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
}

span.rot {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-container">
      <canvas id="canvas">
      </canvas>
   
    <div class="canvas-controls flex">
      <button id="panLeft" title="Pan left"><span>&lArr;</span></button>
      <button id="panRight" title="Pan right"><span>&rArr;</span></button>
      <button id="panUp" title="Pan up"><span>&uArr;</span></button>
      <button id="panDown" title="Pan down"><span>&dArr;</span></button>      
      <button id="rotateLeft" title="Rotate left"><span>&#10226;</span></button>
      <button id="rotateRight" title="Rolotate right"><span>&#10227;</span></button>
      <button id="mirror" title="Mirror"><span>&#8697;</span></button>
      <button id="flip" title="Flip"><span class="rot">&#8697;</span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

More

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering with panning after flipping or mirroring the canvas is related to how the canvas transformations affect the panning direction. When you apply a transformation like flipping or mirroring, it changes the coordinate system of the canvas, which in turn affects the direction of panning.

To solve this issue correctly, you need to keep track of the current transformation state of the canvas and adjust the panning accordingly. You can do this by maintaining a transformation matrix and applying it to your panning operations. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
const transformMatrix = {
  a: 1, // Horizontal scaling
  b: 0, // Vertical skewing
  c: 0, // Horizontal skewing
  d: 1, // Vertical scaling
  e: 0, // Horizontal translation (panning)
  f: 0, // Vertical translation (panning)
};

function applyMatrix() {
  context.setTransform(
    transformMatrix.a,
    transformMatrix.b,
    transformMatrix.c,
    transformMatrix.d,
   transformMatrix.e,
   transformMatrix.f
  );
}

function pan(x, y) {
  transformMatrix.e += x;
  transformMatrix.f += y;
  applyMatrix();
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function mirror() {
  transformMatrix.a *= -1; // Flip horizontally
  applyMatrix();
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function flip() {
  transformMatrix.d *= -1; // Flip vertically
  applyMatrix();
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function reset() {
  // Reset the transformation matrix
  transformMatrix.a = 1;
  transformMatrix.b = 0;
  transformMatrix.c = 0;
  transformMatrix.d = 1;
  transformMatrix.e = 0;
  transformMatrix.f = 0;
  applyMatrix();
  drawImageToCanvas();
}
```

With these modifications, you are now keeping track of the current transformation matrix and applying it to the canvas using setTransform. This ensures that panning, flipping, and mirroring work correctly together, as they take into account the current transformation state of the canvas.

Remember to update your pan, mirror, and flip functions accordingly in your event listeners. With these changes, your canvas should pan correctly after flipping or mirroring without any additional matrices for different angles.

Code snippet:

```js
const IMGURL = "https://i.imgur.com/hjNvQge.jpg";

const CANVASWITH = 500;
const CANVASHEIGHT = 325;
const PANSTEP = 20;

const transformMatrix = {
  a: 1, // Horizontal scaling
  b: 0, // Vertical skewing
  c: 0, // Horizontal skewing
  d: 1, // Vertical scaling
  e: 0, // Horizontal translation (panning)
  f: 0, // Vertical translation (panning)
};

var canvas,
  context,
  image,
  scaledImgWidth,
  scaledImgHeight,
  startX,
  startY,
  canvasCenterX,
  canvasCenterY,
  scale;

window.onload = () => {
  loadImage();
  addEventListeners();
};

function loadImage() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas.width = CANVASWITH;
  canvas.height = CANVASHEIGHT;
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  image = new Image();

  image.onload = function() {
    init();
    reset();
  };
  image.src = IMGURL;
}

function init() {
  scale = Math.min(canvas.width / image.width, canvas.height / image.height);
  scaledImgWidth = image.width * scale;
  scaledImgHeight = image.height * scale;
  startX = (canvas.width - scaledImgWidth) / 2;
  startY = (canvas.height - scaledImgHeight) / 2;
  canvasCenterX = canvas.width / 2;
  canvasCenterY = canvas.height / 2;
  context.save();
}

function drawImageToCanvas() {
  context.save();
  context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.restore();
  context.drawImage(image, startX, startY, scaledImgWidth, scaledImgHeight);
}

function pan(x, y) {
  transformMatrix.e += x;
  transformMatrix.f += y;
  applyMatrix();
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function rotate(degrees) {
  context.translate(canvasCenterX, canvasCenterY);
  context.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * degrees);
  context.translate(-canvasCenterX, -canvasCenterY);
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function mirror() {
  transformMatrix.a *= -1; // Flip horizontally
  applyMatrix();
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function flip() {
  transformMatrix.d *= -1; // Flip vertically
  applyMatrix();
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function reset() {
  // Reset the transformation matrix
  transformMatrix.a = 1;
  transformMatrix.b = 0;
  transformMatrix.c = 0;
  transformMatrix.d = 1;
  transformMatrix.e = 0;
  transformMatrix.f = 0;
  applyMatrix();
  drawImageToCanvas();
}

function applyMatrix() {
  context.setTransform(
    transformMatrix.a,
    transformMatrix.b,
    transformMatrix.c,
    transformMatrix.d,
    transformMatrix.e,
    transformMatrix.f
  );
}

function addEventListeners() {
  document.getElementById("rotateRight").addEventListener("click", function() {
    rotate(90);
  });
  document
    .getElementById("rotateLeft")
    .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      rotate(-90);
    });
  document.getElementById("mirror").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    mirror();
  });
  document.getElementById("flip").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    flip();
  });
  document
    .getElementById("panLeft")
    .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      pan(-PANSTEP, 0);
    });
  document
    .getElementById("panRight")
    .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      pan(PANSTEP, 0);
    });
  document.getElementById("panUp").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    pan(0, -PANSTEP);
  });
  document
    .getElementById("panDown")
    .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      pan(0, PANSTEP);
    });
}
```

```css
.canvas-container {
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

canvas {
  background: #777;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.canvas-controls {
  padding: 5px;
}

button span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
}

span.rot {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="canvas">
      </canvas>

  <div class="canvas-controls flex">
    <button id="panLeft" title="Pan left"><span>&lArr;</span></button>
    <button id="panRight" title="Pan right"><span>&rArr;</span></button>
    <button id="panUp" title="Pan up"><span>&uArr;</span></button>
    <button id="panDown" title="Pan down"><span>&dArr;</span></button>
    <button id="rotateLeft" title="Rotate left"><span>&#10226;</span></button>
    <button id="rotateRight" title="Rolotate right"><span>&#10227;</span></button>
    <button id="mirror" title="Mirror"><span>&#8697;</span></button>
    <button id="flip" title="Flip"><span class="rot">&#8697;</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arun. I have applied the changes in a new CodePen ( https://codepen.io/r-w-c/pen/MWZXbXq ), but not everything works as hoped/expected. The mirror and flip function don't work anymore and when I pan after rotate, mirror or flip, the image goes 'back' (resets) to it's initial state. Any suggestions?